# How to run cronjob with computer shut off (EC2 instance)

Tags: r, amazon-ec2, cron

I outlined my small project in a different post - to summarize it again quickly, I am trying to do the following:

- Write an R script that pulls data from a website
- Schedule the R script to automatically run daily at the same time
- Write / append the R script's output to a database

I am familiar with R web-scraping packages (rvest, rselenium) for doing the first bullet. For the 2nd bullet, just today I learned how to create a crontab to run my script when I desire, however **the crontab does not run the script when my computer is off, or so I've read**.

How can I have it such that the crontab is run even with my computer off? I am somewhat (not really) familiar with EC2 instances, but if I have my R script in an EC2 instance, could I schedule a crontab for the script there and then it would run with my computer off?

Thanks in advance for help!

Comment: I post a lot of questions similar to this and I know they're off topic since they're not programming-specific. Please let me know if there's a better place to post these and I will. Thanks!

Comment: yes you can do this. `ssh` to your ec2, use `scp` to copy `yourscript.R` to the ec2, use e.g. `apt-get install` to install `R` on the ec2, and use `crontab -e` to schedule it, e.g., `Rscript yourscript.R >yourscript.R.log 2>yourscript.R.err`

Comment: Is the database on the local machine? If you want to run the script even when the machine is stopped, how will the script write to the database? Your problem definition is not complete.

Comment: I haven't gotten to bullet point 3 at all on my end yet, haven't started the database - your comment makes me think the database will need to be in the cloud if I want all of this to work with my local computer shut off, right?

Answer (score 1):

Since cron is a service that runs on the instance you can't have it start the EC2 instance for you - it's a catch-22.

You can treat EC2 instances as computers that run in someone else's cellar (most of the time at least). You wouldn't expect a computer to run code when it's not turned on and it's exactly the same for an EC2 instance.

I suggest you consider if this is really the setup you want, it sounds to me that you'd be better served using [AWS Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/) combined with one of Amazon's hosted data stores (RDS, DynamoDB, SimpleDB, or even S3). The downside here is that you're limited to JavaScript, Python, and Java and as such can't use R (well, you can, but it's messy since you'll have to package everything you need in a JS/Python/Java app and start it from there).

If you really want to run your R script on the EC2 instance you can start the instance with a lambda and then shut it down from your script. Just make sure your instance isn't set to terminate on shutdown.

Regardless of what path you chose you will need to create a lambda and run it from a [scheduled CloudWatch Event](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/ScheduledEvents.html).

Then you just need to implement the lambda, either to run your script or to use the EC2 API to start the instance.

If you use the lambda to start the EC2 instance you should not use cron on the instance to run the script at a specific time, but [run it on startup](https://serverfault.com/questions/504716/how-to-run-a-shell-script-on-my-amazon-instance-when-it-bootsup). Then you have your script [shut down the instance](https://superuser.com/questions/711006/how-to-shutdown-ubuntu-server-from-shell-script) when it's finished.

Here's an example Python script for starting an EC2 instance from a lambda to get your started:

```
import logging

import boto3

# Set up logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

# Set up a boto session to get credentials and region
session = boto3.session.Session()

# Set up EC2
ec2 = session.resource("ec2")

# The instance to start
instance_id = "i-1234567890abcd"

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    logger.info('Start handling event.')

    logger.info('Starting instance ' + instance_id)
    instance = ec2.Instance(instance_id)
    response = instance.start()
    try:
        current_state = response['StartingInstances'][0]['CurrentState']
    except (KeyError, IndexError) as e:
        logger.warn('Unexpected response when starting instance: {}'.format(response))
    else:
        if current_state not in ('pending', 'running'):
            logger.warn('Instance {} is in unexpected state {} after starting'.format(id, current_state))
        else:
            logger.info('Started instance ' + instance_id)
```

Comment: couldn't I simply have the instance up and running at all times? and thank you very much for a few database suggestions for this.

Comment: I'm using the smallest instance I can, the t2.micro with Amazon Linux AMI (is that the right way to describe the instance) - this is the free tier one so I can leave it up running at all times for free, no?

Comment: You can keep a t2.micro running for a year on the free tier, it's not the prettiest solution though - especially depending on how often your script runs but if it's the easiest solution for you I'd go for it.